# Can I use Reader mode (as in Safari) in UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, ios9.1

I want convert webpage from my app as safari reader mode. Is it real?

Answer (score 1):

you mean this?

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>

NSString *sURL = @"http://google.com";

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];

SFSafariViewController *safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL]; // 1.

//SFSafariViewController *safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL entersReaderIfAvailable:YES]; // 2.

[self presentViewController:safari animated:YES completion:nil];
```